Waiting to Access the Current Fragment
I have several Fragment(s) and a single FragmentActivity in a .NET for Android app. There are multiple external classes (such as RecyclerView.Adapter) that require access to the current Fragment (I never have more than 1 Fragment visible or active at the same time). In these external classes, I use a line similar to the following to simplify access to the current Fragment:
private readonly SettingsFragment settingsfragment = ((FragmentActivity)Platform.CurrentActivity).SupportFragmentManager.Fragments[0] as SettingsFragment;
This sometimes works, but at other times CurrentActivity returns null. This usually happens when the app attempts to access the external class immediately after I switch between Fragments using a FragmentTransaction similar to the following:
this.Activity.SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction().Replace(Resource.Id.fcvMain, new SettingsFragment()).Commit();
It seems like this is due to the FragmentTransaction having not yet been completed, although it is hard to know for sure. Is there a way to force a Fragment to wait until everything is loaded before trying to continue? Thanks!

Your architecture seems kind of screwed up.  A RecyclerView.Adapter exists for a specific RecyclerView, which will be inside a single Fragment.  So the Fragment should own the RecyclerView.  In general the Adapter shouldn't know or need to know that it's in a Fragment at all, but if it does it should be passed in the constructor for the Adapter.  It really seems like whatever architecture you're going for is making things harder on you.

My RecyclerView.Adapter needs to access the Fragment to call some of it's methods. The ViewHolders for the RecyclerView contain EditTexts, which affect the status of other Views in the Fragment. When you say "it should be passed in the constructor for the Adapter", does that mean passing the Fragment to the Adapter as a parameter? If I cannot access the Fragment inside the Adapter, I would prefer (if possible) to implement some kind of event handler in response to the Notify methods (do these exist?)

Why would the Adapter need to call functions on the fragment?  If it needs to get data like the Activity, pass that in during the constructor.  If its about notification of events like the text changing, you shouldn't be handling that in the Adapter anyway-  the Adapter should be passed a function to call when an event occurs.  The Adapter should not know about or directly manipulate any data or UI outside the RecyclerView and its elements.

They aren't actually functions, just methods to update the UI (enabling/disabling Buttons). The place where I had the calls in a previous version was at the end of OnBindViewHolder. As you know, OnBindViewHolder gets called multiple times (every time an item is updated), so what I would really like would be to have an event (like BindingCompleted) that is triggered once everything is complete. I could add a custom event and invoke it at the end of OnBindViewHolder, but it seems inefficient to invoke it multiple times. Is this what I should do, or is there something better?

You shouldn't want or need to know that binding is completed.  Especially since it never is-  scrolling will create a new set of onBindViewHolder calls.  What are you trying to do with that info?  There's likely a better way to do it

As for removing/disabling buttons outside the recycler view-  that's definitely not something you EVER do in an Adapter.  If an interaction with the views in the adapter requires you to change data, then you should pass in an interface to call when the event occurs, and the Adapter itself should know nothing about what that interface does.  The adapter should be oblivious to the outside world

You are making it hard on yourself.
Use the NavigationComponent. You'll then never need to make a FragmentTransaction manually, as it is all done internally. Your single activity should be AppCompatActivity, which is inherited from FragmentActivity.
Get rid of Platform.CurrentActivity, whatever that is. In a single Activity app, you can refer to Activity when inside a Fragment. There is only one, so it can never be null.
Look at the new project I mentioned the other day with the new BooksFragment, and check how it's RecyclerView.Adapter works.

When I previously tried to learn the NavigationComponent, I found it very confusing. Because my app has only 2 Fragments, I found it easier to use FragmentTransactions (but this is my first single-activity, multi-Fragment app, so maybe I'm just avoiding it). Platform.CurrentActivity is part of Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel, a replacement for Xamarin.Essentials. I needed it because I needed to access the Fragment/Activity from OUTSIDE the Fragment.

I know what it is. I am just being sarcastic about Essentials. Why can't you use your recyclerview like I did in that new project? You certainly don't need anything from Maui.
